# GCC and G++ struct packing differences?

Tags: c, gcc, g++, alignment

I'm using C code in my C++ project which I include using extern "C". I then define structs in my C++ class which are passed to the C code (compiled using gcc). The problem is that when that C code accesses the struct that was defined in the C++ class, I get different alignment and the code reads and writes WRONG data. This seems bizarre but I have been debugging this for 3 hours and basically when I print pointer to a deep member of that struct from C++ code, everything is fine. But if I print the pointer from within C code, the address is different!

Why is this happening and how do I ensure that my alignment is consistent?

(I have double checked that this is NOT an out of date compilation issue by recompiling everything. Still same result. In C the address is 8 bytes before the address to the member as reported in C++ code)

**Edit: the problem was that g++ and gcc would treat empty structs differently. If I had an empty struct foo {} in my code, sizeof my struct would be 1 byte bigger under g++ and all offsets of members would be messed up. So I put a dummy uint8_t into the empty struct so that it would not be empty anymore and all such problems across the codebase seem to have disappeared. Now alignment seems to work the same and struct size is the same as well (for each empty struct g++ would previously add 1 byte). I am not 100% sure what is going on with gcc so if anyone is has anything to add then feel free to fill me in on this**

My gcc version is:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609
```

My compilation flags under gcc are:

```
-std=gnu99 -Wchar-subscripts -Wformat -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wmissing-braces -Wparentheses -Wsequence-point -Wswitch -Wtrigraphs -Wno-unused-function -Wunused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wuninitialized -Wdiv-by-zero -Wfloat-equal -Wdouble-promotion -fsingle-precis
ion-constant -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Wredundant-decls -Wunreachable-code -Winline -Wenum-compare -Wlong-long -Wchar-subscripts -Wextra -Werror -g -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -m32 -fstack-protector -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700 -D_GNU_SOURCE -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs
```

g++

```
-std=c++11 -Wextra -Werror -g -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -m32 -fstack-protector -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700 -D_GNU_SOURCE -ftest-coverage -fprofile-arcs
```

**Edit2: added -pedantic to my C flags to make gcc warn about empty structs. Dropped it previously because it broke many other things and third party headers (we have to use -Werror). Luckily things like macro ({}) statements can be prefixed with __extension__ to make them pass -pedantic. Got a few other things that need to be changed in the codebase. Don't know yet if something will be hard to implement with pedantic enabled. Does anyone know how to only enable warning for empty structs or disable some specific things that pedantic does not allow?**

Comment: Show us what you are doing now.  Then explain exactly what it is you expect from it and what you get instead.

Comment: cpp file compiled with g++: printf("%p", &data.substruct.foo) -> 00a79e08. Then call cfunction_dosomething(&data). Then in file compiled with gcc: cfunction_dosomething(struct data *self) -> printf("%p", &self->substruct.foo) -> 00a79e00

Comment: Oh come on. 1800 rep and you post code in comments?

Comment: You should put relevant code and such in the question rather than a comment.  And more context would be helpful.  Try to get it to a minimal complete verifiable example because there's just too much missing to really understand what is going on.

Comment: I have not isolated the issue into a small example yet. The struct data is a large hierarchical structure with many objects in it. Usually all code is C but now we have some C++ code that we use on top so we link both C and C++ code together. I have tried linking using both gcc and g++ so far. Same result.

Comment: HA! wouldn't you have guessed. Compiling C++ code with -std=c++14 instead of -std=c++11 makes everything work. Pathetic. gcc version 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: Could it be that the struct defined in the C++ file is compiled using C++ semantics and therefore has a `this` pointer that you're not expecting to be there?

Comment: How do I check? And why would it work when built as c++14 but not when built as c++11? Have the semantics changed somehow?

Comment: Btw, C code is built with -std=gnu99 if that would make any difference.

Comment: @EdKing - What `this` pointer? A `this` pointer is an artefact of member functions.

Comment: Put the solution in an Answer, not as an edit to the Question.

Comment: @StoryTeller - Sorry, I actually meant the default constructor, and whether that was putting things out of bonk.

Comment: I have posted my solution below.

Comment: You might be able to make `-pedantic` less of a pain by having it used only on a single `.c` file that includes all the headers you're concerned about instead of using it across all `.c` files.  Apply it only to the simplest `.c` file so warnings will only be triggered for code/declarations in the headers. Or maybe even add a special file to your build that does nothing but include the headers for the purpose of getting the pedantic warnings for the headers.

Comment: I'm also curious if the C++11 vs C++14 difference was a red herring or if G++ actually treats empty structs differently somehow between those two language versions.

Comment: Yes standard switch turned out to be a false positive.

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution seems to be to never define empty structs in code that will be used across C++ -> C boundary. I had a:

```
struct spinlock { }
```

that was empty when building against a single processor target. So g++ would make this 1 byte while gcc would just discard it. Therefore my structs would be different size and offsetof would even return different results depending on whether the code was built with gcc or g++.

So I changed it to

```
struct spinlock { uint8_t dummy; }
```

and now my structs align perfectly and everything works without any special C++ standard specification.

Answer (score 1):

Empty structures gets you a couple of implementation defined or non-standard behaviors.  First of all empty structures aren't supported in standard C. GCC supports them in as an extension with a size == 0.

C++ supports empty structs, but mandates that they have a non-zero size when used as a "most derived object". However, C++ also allows classes/structs that inherit from empty structs to optimize that size away for the subclass.

Comment: Do you know how to make it warn about empty structs without having to use -pedantic? (pedantic breaks things like switch ranges and basically all other elegant extensions)

Comment: What's really disturbing is that the behavior is different between gcc and g++. Had it been the same, code would at least work correctly when something that contains empty structs gets defined in c++ and then passed to a c function. When things work differently in this way it creates really hard to find overflows. C code will think that all data after the empty struct is in a completely different place from where it really is if the struct was declared in a c++ file.

Comment: Since it passes compilation just fine without -pedantic, everything will work fine MOST of the time because C++ struct will always be bigger and if only C code operates on the struct data nothing will break. Until you try to set struct members in C++ and pass the struct to underlying C code for processing only to discover later that C code sees a totally different picture shifted by 1, 2, 3 or more bytes.

Comment: I don't know of a way to disable or warn on the C zero-sized struct extension.  You are right that there should be a way to disable it (or force it to act the same as C++) since it silently causes the incompatibility that you ran into.  If you opened a GCC bug on this, I suspect they'd be open to adding such an option, but even so it would likely be years.  It's far from an ideal suggestion, but if you're using a unit test framework you could probably come up with fairly simple tests that verify that C and C++ see structures as having the same size/layout.